# Why does java not work in chrome in ubuntu?

Tags: java, google-chrome

I know it doesn't work, and I just want to know why.

Comment: Google chrome/chromium no longer supports netscape plugins.

Comment: Okay... that is a bit vague.

Comment: http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is a [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) plugin. Support for NPAPI was dropped in Chrome/Chromium 34 due to the transition to the [Aura UI stack](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/aura/aura-overview). As such, Java will not work in Chrome/Chromium >34.